# when participating in an ICO do i need to download a specific wallet for that new coin

Tags: wallets, ico

My question is about ICO wallets. when participating in an ICO do i need to download a specific wallet for that new coin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a wallet for which you and only you have full control of the private key.

A "wallet" is not a great name for an ethereum address, it is a hold over from when there was only one coin, bitcoin.

"Wallet" is just an analogy and its not a good one for etherum.

Everything in etherum is built around **signed transactions**. Your private key allows you and only you to **sign** transactions. You can think of it as a mathamagical rubber stamp.

### You can think of an ERC20 as a checkbook from the bank of that token. Anyone can write anything they want in a checkbook, but it isn't worth anything until its signed.

If you can **sign** transactions you can send ERC20 tokens.

Hardware wallets are your best bet. Failing that you might try installing https://brave.com/ where metamask is a builtin plugin.

You can send tokens via https://www.myetherwallet.com/

As an aside, you can think of your public address as a **official letter head** its public and for everyone to see, but it isn't worth anything without your private **signature**.

Never share your private key!

Comment: okay thanks and are do some ICO's need invitation links?

Comment: @Etherneum yes some ICO's do. Some ICO's have to follow the "Know Your Customers" laws as well.

Comment: kyc rings a bell thanks, any recommendations in particular when analyzing an ICO and if its a winner or loser or a scam?